# Core Data - database not found when Updating App on App Store

Tags: ios, core-data, app-store, icloud, updates

We have an app currently up on the app Store. Recently we put up a new version that now uses a preloaded Core Data database.

When a user does a fresh install of the new version, there is no problem.

When a user updates from a previous version, there is an issue. The app appears blank and it's as if it can't find the Core Data database.

I thought there was only migration issues when changing Core Data model. Is there also migration issues I should look out for when updated an existing app from using no Core data to using Core Data?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: How do you preload the core data database? Please post your code.

Comment: The issue was due to the database being automatically created before the code to add the preloaded database was being called. Thanks!